How to type .watch() change stream events in Mongoose with TypeScript?
I'm using .watch() on a Mongoose collection and would like to type the incoming change stream data for TypeScript. However, I haven't been able to find a Mongoose type for this. Does a specific type exist for .watch() events in Mongoose, or is there a recommended way to define one?
Here's a simplified example of my code:
ExampleSchema.watch()
  .on('change', (data: SomeMongooseType) => {
    // handle the change event
  });

I noticed the Mongoose documentation includes examples of the structure of data returned by .watch(), but no type definitions are provided.
Example of the data value from the Mongoose documentation:
{
  _id: {
    _data: '8262408DAC000000012B022C0100296E5A10042890851837DB4792BE6B235E8B85489F46645F6964006462408DAC6F5C42FF5EE087A20004'
  },
  operationType: 'insert',
  clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1648397740, i: 1 }),
  fullDocument: {
    _id: new ObjectId("62408dac6f5c42ff5ee087a2"),
    name: 'Axl Rose',
    __v: 0
  },
  ns: { db: 'test', coll: 'people' },
  documentKey: { _id: new ObjectId("62408dac6f5c42ff5ee087a2") }
}

Thanks in advance for any insights!
